# Difference between JDBC driver vs Python Adapters for Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, python-db-api

To connect Amazon Redshift, I used the python `psycopg2` module to inject the dataset on Amazon Redshift and it is working fine. Just to mention that I'm using the Redshift's endpoint URL to connect via the `psycopg2` which underneath uses python DB API v2.0. Amazon Redshift also provides the JDBC or ODBC URL to connect but I'm not using this.

**pseudo-code:**

```
import psycopg2
try:
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "redshift_user",
                                  password = "redshift_password",
                                  host = "redshift_endpoint",
                                  port = "5432",
                                  database = "redshift_database")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

**Note:** I also use the same endpoint of Redshift to connect it from my different clients like Tableau, Navicat Premium or other SQL clients that use JDBC/ODBC driver underneath it.

But recently Amazon sent me to message about JDBC driver update,

> AWS Redshift identified an issue in Redshift JDBC drivers that led to
>   unexpected server restarts, which was subsequently fixed in the latest
>   Redshift JDBC drivers. Some of your clusters in the US-WEST-2 Region
>   are registering connections from older versions of the JDBC driver and
>   might be affected by this issue.
>
> Please upgrade your driver to the latest version: 1.2.36.1060, which
>   is available for download [1].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html#download-jdbc-driver

**So now I have a couple of question-**

1. The psycopyg2 module is using the JDBC or ODBC driver underneath it?
2. The above message from AWS is because of the different clients I used that underneath is using the older version of JDBC or ODBC drivers. So I've to update the drivers of my clients only not on my `psycopg2` module.

Comment: JDBC is the Java DataBase Connectivity API, and ODBC is the Open DataBase Connectivity API. There is no such thing as JDBC/ODBC (except as a - now removed - JDBC driver in Java that bridged to an ODBC driver).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel know it, sir, thanks for the reply, but my confusion now is may I need to update my SQL client's JDBC driver? or Python's psycopg2 module to avoid the AWS warning? also JDBC/ODBC I mean JDBC **or** ODBC

Comment: I have never used psycopg2, but according to https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2#psycopg2---python-postgresql-database-adapter it wraps libpq, which is a PostgreSQL native library, so it doesn't use a JDBC driver.

Comment: psycopg2 is now psycopg2-binary, rest all remains the same. See if you can updgrade to that and if the issue is still there.

Comment: According the aws redshift documentataion https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/python-connect-examples.html the examples they give use the `redshift_connector` database connector module. I would use this over `psycopg2`.